# How to Get Software Updates in Offline Mode for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, updates

Right now my home PC isn't connected to the internet. My office PC however is connected with internet.

I want to install updates on my home PC. Updates for iTunes, Xcode, Safari, QuickTime, Java etc. I don't want to download entire setups for that ones.

I have seen many anti-virus software giving the updates in a file.
That file contains the update data. I store it to my PC & updates the antivirus system.
( for example Anti-vir Avira does this. )

Does Apple provide the same?
If yes, how?
If no, What to do?

Would you help me in updating the PC without a net connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple lets you download the programs just the same from their website in most cases.  Usually, an update just involves replacing the existing application in the applications folder with the new one. This includes common applications such as Safari, iTunes, etc.

For things that aren't as easy such as quicktime updates, you should check the apple support page since they usually allow you to download the updates.

Once you have the updates, put them on a USB Key and run them on home mac.

I'd start here http://www.apple.com/downloads/ . For some items that are more integral to the system, they might only be available through Software Update in the Apple Menu.

Answer (score 3):

If you know which update files you need, most can be downloaded from http://support.apple.com/downloads/, so you could download them at work and bring them home on a USB drive or other device.

Answer (score 1):

You can download standalone software updaters from Software Update; look under the "Update" menu item and select "Download only." They will download to Harddrive/Library/Packages/

For standalone system software updaters to carry on a USB drive, it's a good idea to get the Combo Updaters, which cover more "jumps" in OS versions, and are the recommended fix for software updates that don't go as planned (by booting from a USB or Firewire drive and reapplying the Combo Update).